# Edit one row in a list of records?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have a list of records, e.g. addresses. It's displayed using the following html5/knockout code.

```
<section id="lists" data-bind="foreach: addresses, visible: addresses().length > 0">
    <article>
        <div>
            <button>Edit</button>
            <span data-bind="text: DisplayAddress"></span>
        </div>
        <p class="error" data-bind="visible: ErrorMessage, text: ErrorMessage"></p>
    </article>
</section>
```

I want to show a table of editable input boxes () under the row after *Edit* button is clicked. Is there any way without generate a big html5 code?

I want to show the following *editing* html below the `<div>` after click the *Edit* button. (not completed)

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Street address</th><th>Apt#</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Zip</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" class="col1"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="col2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="col3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="col4"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="col5"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button data-bind="click: saveAddress">Save</button>
    <button data-bind="click: cancelAdding">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you expect to display a table without inserting it into DOM unless it already exists in DOM? Really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I don't know much about it but could using a Flash object be a possibility?

Comment: @charlietfl you are right. I've removed the not inserting DOM requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasonable options:

1) Use the [if](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) binding to control the rendering (not just visibility) of a block of HTML. Each row of data would have an observable property called `isEditing`. Then, add behavioral functions to control edit/cancel/etc. Your article template would include something like the following:

```
<div data-bind="if:isEditing">
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: DisplayAddress" />
</div>
```

2) If it's just one field, you might want to create a custom binding handler that adds the behavior you want to an element (it would dynamically add/remove a field). There are a few good examples on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354491/knockout-inline-edit-binding) of this technique.